# Arduino error: expected unqualified-id before 'else'

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

The Arduino console gives me: expected unqualified-id before 'else'
What's wrong with my code?

Here's the code
http://pastebin.com/esU80naM

If you can, also give me repaired code on pastebin

Thanks!

Problem is with line 164 in pastebin
else if (digitalRead(c3)==LOW){

Comment: The code is horribly formatted, how are we supposed to know which `else`  you are talking about ??

Comment: Relevant code should be pasted into question, not on external site.

Comment: If you try to reformat your code you will se a missing `{` on your first `if`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple and obvious typo and the error message already tells you everything you need to know. Change:

```
if(digitalRead(c0)==LOW);
```

to:

```
if(digitalRead(c0)==LOW){
```

Note that the error reported by the compiler relates to an `else` clause without a preceding `if`, so you need to work backwards from the reported error to find the source of the problem. This is quite common and you will no doubt encounter similar problems again in the future.